# Coordinate in List

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out how to search for a character in a string of character that will output its coordinate.

I am trying to search for the character 'A'

The list is:

```
["OPQ","EAB","XGV"]
```

The function is:

```
searchA :: [[Char]] -> (Int,Int)
```

The user then calls the function as such:

```
searchA ["OPQ","EAB","XGV"]
```

I am expecting an output of (1,1)

Sorry guys, new to stackoverflow and haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code which solve your task:

```hs
import Data.List (find)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

-- ...

searchA :: [[Char]] -> Maybe (Int,Int)
searchA css = do
    (n, cs) <- find (elem 'A' . snd) (zip [0..] css)
    (m, _)  <- find ((== 'A') . snd) (zip [0..] cs)
    return (n,m)
```

Here output type is `Maybe (Int,Int)` because you can not found letter `'A'`.

If you actually want type `(Int,Int)`, you can use `fromJust` function, but your code will be unsafe:

```hs
searchA' :: [[Char]] -> (Int,Int)
searchA' css =
    let (n, cs) = fromJust $ find (elem 'A' . snd) (zip [0..] css)
        (m, _)  = fromJust $ find ((== 'A') . snd) (zip [0..] cs)
    in  (n,m)
```

You can also use function `ifind` from package `lens`:

```hs
import Control.Lens (ifind)

searchA'' :: [[Char]] -> (Int,Int)
searchA'' css =
    let (n, cs) = fromJust $ ifind (\_ -> elem 'A') css
        (m, _)  = fromJust $ ifind (\_ -> (== 'A')) cs
    in  (n,m)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the answer. There will always be an 'A' only the position changes. So do I need to define the functions fromJust and find?

Comment: @Satria No, they are standard functions: `find` from `Data.List` and `fromJust` from `Data.Maybe`

Comment: I see, and what do you mean by unsafe, by using fromJust? Since I know that there will always be 'A' just that the position changes.

Comment: @Satria Well, if you know that there will always be 'A', you can use `searchA'`. But in general case (if there is input without 'A') this code will be able to fail

Comment: I see, thank you so much. Sorry to ask but is there a simpler way to do this, such as using filter?

Comment: @Satria I've updated my answer, last code is maybe simpler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231244/discussion-between-satria-and-sergeykuz1001).

Comment: Hey, anyway to do this only using prelude functions?